# Analogy between Integration and Summation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

There are many analogies between definite integral and Summation: $$\int_a^b \leftrightarrow \sum_a^b$$, This makes me wonder if there is analogous concept of indefinite integral, derivative and anythings like that? More generally, is there any "discrete version" of calculus?? thanks.

Comment: With Lebesgue integration, summation is just integration with the counting measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For derivatives, the most apt analogy is finite differences.

The "calculus" of finite differences is very important, for instance, in designing control algorithms and signal processing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called [Umbral calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus).

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://notes.komputerwiz.net:8000/w/images/1/11/Gleich_2005_-_Finite_Calculus.pdf) is a nice exposition of what the author calls "Finite Calculus". It might answer some of your questions.